# <a> inline not working

Tags: html, css

I'd like to ask you if you know, how can I make it (which property should I set up) to make the "test" events (one is red other is green) in that calendar stand inline (not each on each row). There would be at most 4 event (25% width per each). Speaking about this elements:

```
<a href="/component/dpcalendar/event/1" class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start fc-event-end dpcal-module_event_dpcal_198" style="float: left;position: absolute; left: 93px; border-color: rgb(18, 163, 18); width: 23px; top: 146px; background-color: rgb(18, 163, 18);" data-original-title="" title="">
```

I am dealing with this problem on our website, based on Joomla, where I've uploaded this dpcalendar component - http://www.drnky.cz.

I tried to apply float: left, display: inline, changed the width but nothing helped. Do you know where is the problem, please? :) Thanks a lot.

http://jsfiddle.net/2th7x9ng/

Comment: do you want like this http://screencast.com/t/3Nu9TcuJEW

Comment: @UnicoRahul: Yeah, but.. there's a problem that if I override it in CSS via setting the left and top absolute position, than any new event is in this position (it doesn't work as calendar but as a one-day notepad :( ).. So I think I have to change it somehow in the .js code. That's why I only asked if it is possible just to "inline" these elements and not to roughly set their absolute position :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the elements use the property `position: absolute`, float will have no effect on this.

You can simply change the `left` and `top` settings of the second element to the following and they will be aligned:

```
position: absolute;
left: 103px;
border-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
width: 23px;
top: 146px;
background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Yeah, but.. there's a problem that if I override it in CSS via setting the left and top absolute position, than any new event is in this position (it doesn't work as calendar but as a one-day notepad :( ).. So I think I have to change it somehow in the .js code. That's why I only asked if it is possible just to "inline" these elements and not to roughly set their absolute position :(

Comment: I indeed believe you should do it through the javascript. Or do you have a way to add your code in the corresponding <td> in your calendar?

Comment: Thank You - finally I did it as you can see on the http://www.drnky.cz webpage :) I only "positioned" the parent div to -22px (top) and -2 px (left) :) Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

While using `position: absolute` you need to control your and style it by yourself. `float` will not work with `position: absolute`. So you need to change your `left` and `top` to place your `green` and `red` bullets hyperlinks wherever you want in the calender.

Just use the following style for your anchor tags in your calender at your website. I tested it live on your website and it solves your problem by showing both in the same line.

**For green link:**

```
position: absolute;
left: 93px;
border-color: rgb(18, 163, 18);
width: 23px;
top: 146px;
background-color: rgb(18, 163, 18);
```

**For red link:**

```
position: absolute;
left: 102px;
border-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
width: 23px;
top: 146px;
background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
```

### EDIT 2:

```
<a href="/component/dpcalendar/event/1" class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start fc-event-end dpcal-module_event_dpcal_198" style="float: left;position: absolute; left: 93px; border-color: rgb(18, 163, 18); width: 23px; top: 146px; background-color: rgb(18, 163, 18);" data-original-title="" title=""><div class="fc-event-inner"><span class="fc-event-title">&nbsp;</span></div></a>
<a href="/component/dpcalendar/event/2" class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-start fc-event-end dpcal-module_event_dpcal_198" style="position: absolute; left: 102px; border-color: rgb(204, 0, 0); width: 23px; top: 146px; background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);" data-original-title="" title=""><div class="fc-event-inner"><span class="fc-event-title">&nbsp;</span></div></a>
```

Working [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/nbcs91xk/)

Comment: Thank You Joker. Should I do it like this for other events? 
`.fc-event-container a:nth-child(2) { left: 102px!important; top: 146px!important; }`

Comment: Yeah. If you want to override it with CSS then it is the way to do it. `.fc-event-container a:nth-child(1)` is for the first anchor tag and `.fc-event-container a:nth-child(2)` is for the second anchor tag.

Comment: You have applied inline style to your elements. Either you go and modify your inline style OR you can simple override it with the `CSS` that you have written in the comment above.

Comment: Yeah, but.. there's a problem that if I override it in CSS via setting the left and top absolute position, than any new event is in this position (it doesn't work as calendar but as a one-day notepad :( ).. So I think I have to change it somehow in the .js code. That's why I only asked if it is possible just to "inline" these elements and not to roughly set their absolute position :(